# How to Run some script forever without causing cpu fan overspeed in Linux

Tags: bash

I want to apply dark theme depending on if it is "AM" or "PM".  So I have created a bash script with "while loop" (So that it runs forever).

But running this script causes speed up in cpu fan. (that happens when our pc struggles to do something highly computational or playing game or anything heavy).

My script is just a simple line. So how can I run this script without causing high fan speeding?

```
#!/bin/bash
isNightThemeApplied=0
isDayThemeApplied=0
while [[ 1 -le 1 ]]
do
  if [[ `date +%r` == *"AM"* ]]
  then
    if [[ isNightThemeApplied -eq 0 ]]
    then
      echo "Applying Night Theme..."
      lookandfeeltool -a 'org.kde.breezedark.desktop'
      isNightThemeApplied=1
      isDayThemeApplied=0
      echo "Night Theme Applied Successfully" 
    fi
  else
    if [[ isDayThemeApplied -eq 0 ]]
    then
      echo "Applying Day Theme..."
      lookandfeeltool -a 'org.kde.breeze.desktop'
      isDayThemeApplied=1
      isNightThemeApplied=0
      echo "Day Theme Applied Successfully"
    fi
  fi
done
```

Comment: It's not necessary to continuously check. A very simple fix would be just to sleep for some time, e.g. 1 hour, and then do the checks. The process will not use any CPU whilst it's asleep. Or use something like `cron` to schedule the script.

Comment: The most simple way would be to add a delay like `sleep 60` or `sleep 1` in the loop. This would avoid repeating the checks as fast as possible. Better would be to run the commands at specified times. I don't know if it is possible to run the command from `cron`. See e.g. https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/8207td/change_the_theming_based_on_the_time/

Comment: The biggest step is definitely to change `while [[ 1 -le 1 ]]` to something like `while sleep 60; do` or similar. However, beyond that, the use of `date` is very inefficient here. It's much better to use bash's built-in time-formatting functionality -- see f/e `printf -v part_of_day '%(%p)T' -1` to put either `AM` or `PM` in the variable `part_of_day` (subject to current locale settings; safest to set `LC_ALL=C` to guarantee identical behavior everywhere).

Comment: Why not set up a cron job to switch between them at noon and midnight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this that uses a while loop every 30 minutes so hardly resource hungry, no need to echo anything in my opinion, just put this in your start up script and run it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

a=$(date +%p)
b="PM"
c="AM"

theme_change () {
    
if [[ "$a" == "$b" ]] ; then
    lookandfeeltool -a 'org.kde.breezedark.desktop'
elif [[ "$a" == "$c" ]] ; then
    lookandfeeltool -a 'org.kde.breeze.desktop'    
fi

}

while true; do
  theme_change;
  sleep 1800;
done
```